# Angular.js UI-Grid external filtering causes empty grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

When I externally filter data in ui-grid, in my success function, i see the correctly filtered data coming back from my service.  But when I apply it, the grid is empty.

Initially, without filters, I get all the results I expect.

Any idea why the data isn't showing up?

```
app.controller('GridController', ['$scope', '$http', 'uiGridConstants', function ($scope, $http, uiGridConstants) {

    var paginationOptions = {
        pageNumber: 1,
        pageSize: 25,
        sort: null
    };

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        enableFiltering: true,
        useExternalSorting: false,
        paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 75],
        paginationPageSize: 25,
        useExternalPagination: true,
        columnDefs: Mapping(type, $scope),
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
            $scope.gridApi.core.on.filterChanged($scope, function () {
                HandleFiltering(this.grid.columns);
            });
            $scope.gridApi.core.on.sortChanged($scope, function (grid, sortColumns) {
                if (sortColumns.length == 0) {
                    paginationOptions.sort = null;
                } else {
                    paginationOptions.sort = sortColumns[0].sort.direction;
                }
                Get();
            });
            gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged($scope, function (newPage, pageSize) {
                paginationOptions.pageNumber = newPage;
                paginationOptions.pageSize = pageSize;
                Get();
            });
        }
    };

    var HandleFiltering = function (gridColumns) {
        for (var i = 0; i < gridColumns.length; i++)
        {
            CreateFilterObject(gridColumns[i], $scope);
        }
        Get();

    }

    var Get = function () {
        debugger;
        AjaxStart();

        var searchRequest = SearchRequest(paginationOptions.pageNumber,
                                           paginationOptions.pageSize,
                                           $scope.objectFilter);


        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: Service+ "/api/" + type + "/Search",
            data: searchRequest,

            success: function (data) {
                $scope.gridOptions.totalItems = data[0];
                $scope.gridOptions.data = data[1];
                var firstRow = (paginationOptions.pageNumber - 1) * paginationOptions.pageSize;

                debugger;
                $scope.$apply();
                AjaxEnd();
            },
            error: function (event, response, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
                AjaxError(response);
                AjaxEnd();
            },


        });
    }

    Get();
}]);
```

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: if you are returning JSON as a part of your 'data' packet, shouldn't you have $scope.gridOptions.data = JSON.parse(data[1])?

Comment: Nah, its coming back as JSON already.  Turns out I was missing "UseExternalFiltering"

Comment: Ah, I am glad it was something simple :).